# Grafana x-axis to show data with 10 seconds granularity instead of 1 sec

Tags: data-visualization, influxdb, grafana

It's probably something easy but I'm new to grafana so bear with me.
I have data collected every 10 seconds I would like to display in Grafana.

```
select time, value from "metrics_value" where instance='Processor' and type='counter' and type_instance='message' and time> now() - 1m;
name: metrics_value
---------------
time            value
2016-10-13T09:24:33Z    23583
2016-10-13T09:24:43Z    23583
2016-10-13T09:24:53Z    23583
2016-10-13T09:25:03Z    23583
2016-10-13T09:25:13Z    23583
```

But it's shown as :

[image: Grafana chart]

So it fills in the intermediate points with some values. 
How could I set the interval of x axis of grafana to show only points of 10 seconds?
I know the I could aggregate summarize function to sum up as described here: [How to change the x axis in Graphite/Grafana (to graph by day)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309710/how-to-change-the-x-axis-in-graphite-grafana-to-graph-by-day)
But I don't think I can use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works properly with:

```
select sum("value") from "metrics_value" where instance='Processor' and type='counter' and type_instance='message' and time> now() - 1m GROUP BY time(10s) fill(null);
```

Edit: I also changed "sum" aggregation to mean so grafana calculates the mean of the values when zoomed out. (Otherwise it summed the values.)